# telling the difference between slack variables and original variables in Z3

Tags: z3

I'm trying to create a new kind of cut to replace the gomory cuts implemented in Z3.
I designed my cut to work with the original constraint entered by the user.
Unfortunately I found out that the Z3 preprocessing of the constraints adds slack variables and changes the structure of the constraints.
I can adapt my algorithm to work with the Z3 constraint structure and the slack variables, but a crucial part of the algorithm requires knowing which variables are slack variables and which are original variables.
I could not find anything in the Z3 source code to help me do that.
I also tried searching online for a solution but couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Do you add your cuts before you invoke Z3? Or, are you modifying the theory_arith class? Did you take a look at the file `src/smt/theory_arith_int.h`?

Comment: I am trying to modify the thoery_arith class. I've already studied the 'src/smt/theory_srith_int.h' file and the code in it that generates gomory cuts but I didn't find an answer to my problem in that file

Answer (score 3):

In the method `mk_gomory_cut(row const & r)` in the file `src/smt/theory_arith_int.h`, `r` is a row of the Simplex tableau. Moreover, the base variable `x_i` is integer, but it assigned to a non-integer value.

The iterator `it` is used to traverse the row entries. Each entry is essentially a pair `a_ij` and `x_j`, where `a_ij` is a numeral and `x_j` is a (theory) variable.

The theory_arith is a plugin for the solver defined in the file `src/smt/smt_context.h`. This solver combines many theory plugins such as theory_arith. It maintains a mapping from expressions to theory variables. This mapping is stored in an object called `enode`.

The method `get_enode(v)` retrieves the enode associated with the theory variable `v`.
Moreover, `get_enode(v)->get_owner()` returns the expression associated with the theory variable `v`.

Now, suppose we want to test whether a theory variable `v` is a slack or not.
First, we can retrieve the associated expression using:

```
   app * t = to_app(get_enode(v)->get_owner())
```

I used the `to_app` because the theory plugins only process ground terms (i.e., they do not contain free variables). 
The variable `v` is a slack if `t` a composite arithmetical term such as `(+ a b)` or `(* a b c)`. That is, a *slack* is essentially a "name" for a composite arithmetical term. 
We can test this using:

```
  t->get_family_id() == get_id()
```

If this expression evaluates to `true`, then `t` is a composite arithmetical term, and consequently `v` is a slack.

Remark: `get_id()` is a method of `theory_arith`. Actually, every theory plugin has this method.